# Insert text from Word into a mail based on a value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel Worksheet with a lot rows. Based on a value in one column I want to insert text from a word document into a e-mail.

I tried to use Copy/paste, but i'm not able to get data from the Paste function. It is import for me to keep the formats.

Any solution ?

```
Dim Outlook_App As Object
Dim Outlook_Mail As Object


Dim wordapp As Object
Dim IntKalkLinieNr As Integer
Dim VarRetVal As Variant
Dim StrFilnavn As String

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

IntKalkLinieNr = 16
StrFilnavn = CStr(Worksheets("Kalkulation").Range("X" & CStr(IntKalkLinieNr)).Value)

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wordapp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Add
wordapp.CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = False
wordapp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

wordapp.Selection.InsertFile Filename:=StrFilnavn, ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False, Attachment:=False
wordapp.Selection.WholeStory
wordapp.Selection.Copy


Set Outlook_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Outlook_Mail = Outlook_App.CreateItem(0)
'    On Error Resume Next
With Outlook_Mail
    .To = "ln@unik.dk"
    .Subject = "Tilbud"
    .Body = wordapp.Selection.Paste
    .Display
End With


WordDoc.Close SaveChange:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Word.Quit
```